# Horror robot film set in a post-apocalyptic landscape with a killer robot or war against robots

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, robots

80s or early 90s film set in a post-apocalyptic landscape with a killer robot or war against robots. In the film a robot comes up behind a woman and squeezes her until blood pops out of her mouth and she is dropped to ground, dead. Any ideas what film this is?

Comment: So are killer robots a known aspect of the landscape (as might be expected in a war) or is it something unexpected? Do you remember whether the woman was caucasian or dark-skinner? Blond or brunette? Long or short hair? Was the robot humanoid?

Comment: I think the robot was humanoid and I have a vague recollection of some kind of war against the robots. I think the woman had dark hair and there was a child involved. I saw this film as a kid or young teenager hence the 80s/early 90s date. It had a very Mad-Max-y-dystopian look about it, very red and junky. It certainly had the visual style of Hardware from what I can tell but not the same context (I think ...).

Answer (score 7):

This might be [Screamers (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

The movie is about a long-running war that has deployed automated robots that burrow around and jump out at targets with bladed edges.  The robots have continued to adapt and have started to develop humanoid decoys so as to lure more targets, as well as indiscriminately targeting both human sides in the war.

The burrowing blades are Type-1s.  The main character in the film uncovers evidence of Type-3s, which pose as helpless children that just want hugs.  The reveal of Type-2s ends up being of self-aware humanoid units, one of which is a soldier accompanying him, who does hug and squeeze one of the other characters to death.

Comment: The squeezing death is about an hour twenty four into this version: https://youtu.be/BjN0HYvd5E0?t=1h24m4s